# Displaying survey questions one at a time MVC mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to develop page for displaying survey questions on a mobile view using mvc. I have to display one question at a time and on clicking next it should display next question.

Am having hard time to achieve this. I initially thought I could using paging, as all the questions are inside a List collection. but then I get struck on how to save the answers selected by user for each questions. From performance side its wise to send a collection back to business layer to save all the selected answers to DB rather than one at a time.

For desktop browser I displayed all the questions on single page and one submit button at the end of the page. So on there is no issue with this one. Problem arises with mobile view.

So could someone please suggest on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance,

Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From performance side its wise to send a collection back to business layer to save all the selected answers to DB rather than one at a time. - i dont think it would be much of a performance issue.

still.there are multiple options for the work you wanna do.

1. Use cookies as the storage mechanism - this way answers can be stored as key values pairs key being the index of the question.

   this way every time you request a new question using ajax via jquery or simpel post back you can you can set cookie to the answer you have got.
2. save it at server side using [session storage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7863/ASP-NET-Session-Management-Internals) same as key value pairs.
3. [use HTML 5 storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).

you can use [this](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.localStorage) to store data at client side using jquery

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I will try your options for saving the data. Regarding displaying the questions on clicking Next, how can I achieve this. Are you suggesting to read one question at a time and display to user? I already have a list collection of questions on controller side. So is there a neat way to show from collection one at a time?

Comment: arent you already using paging?? if not you can keep the page number in query string

Answer (score 0):

I would store the questions in a database. Then each user, if the site is accessed via a mobile device (could detect via JavaScript) you would then save a field in their info (in the database) containing the index of the question that they're up to. I think this is a good idea as it would work cross device, if they start on a phone, then move to a tablet, their 'session' will still persist. Then when they're up to the next question, change the index, and query the database using the user's question index for the relevant information to produce the question.

Comment: Thanks HennyH, thats a good idea. I will note this and based on the time I will implement it.